# CMAltimeter in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, altitude, pressure, cmaltimeter

The background has been ask million here but it is still my problem.
In my app I want to track user altitude and pressure in the background by CMAltimeter.
I want to to use Location Update but the change Apple reject my app very high.

Comment: If you find any solution, Please share

Comment: Any word on this?

Comment: I found a solution, see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636205/4667835), you just have to use `CoreLocation` and background location updates to access altitude. I don't think this goes against AppStore's rules in any point, actually this seems to be the only way Apple lets developers access altitude values in the background.