# Measure iPhone altitude whilst running in background

Tags: ios, swift, cmaltimeter

I am using Swift to write an iPhone App which tracks an aircraft taking off and landing (as indicated by a change in air pressure).

For this I need to measure the iPhone's air pressure whilst it is running in the background. I need to measure the pressure at intervals of at least once every minute for a period of an hour or 2. I have read the [Apple Developer Background Execution guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), but I don't think any of the background modes are relevant; for example, a finite-length task does not last long enough and a fetch task seems to be too infrequent.

My current code to obtain air pressure is as follows:

```
let opQueue = OperationQueue.current!
opQueue.qualityOfService = .background
altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: opQueue) { (data, error) in
      print ("Pressure returned")
      //If pressure returned from iPhone correctly:
      if let data = data {
          self.localPressure = convertPressure(data.pressure.doubleValue, fromUnit: .kPa, toUnit: .hPa) //In hPa
      }
}
```

I have changed the `QoS` of this `operationQueue` to `.background`, but as I understand it, this just makes this a lower priority to get updated & has nothing to do with running as a background execution (correct?).

Is there anything else I can try to periodically obtain the air pressure under a background execution? I can't imagine that obtaining the air pressure every minute or so would use a huge amount of power, so I would hope that it would be possible.

Any help available would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the `cos` attribute of an `OperationQueue` only changes its priority, setting it to `background` won't make your app run in the background.

As for getting altitude data in the background, you should use the `CoreLocation` library rather than the `CoreMotion` and use background location updates.

You have to make your class conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, start the location updates and then implement the following delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }
    let altitude = currentLocation.altitude
    //use altitude to check whether plane is taking off or landing
}
```

Behind the scenes, the system is most probably using `CMAltimeter` to get the altitude data, but there is no API to get it in the background, hence you have to use `CoreLocation`.

Comment: CLLocation will get the altitude from the GPS, not from the pressure sensor. But if you only need the data once per minute for a plane that is taking off/landing, then GPS is good enough anyways, and you won't need the extra sensitivity of the pressure sensor.

Comment: That's good to know, I though `CLLocation` gets its data from `CMAltimeter` as well. However,AFAIK sadly there's no API to access `CMAltimeter` from the background and receive updates from it, so using location updates is the only way even if you would need better precision.